# Using mysqldump with WHERE clause but WHERE clause only applying to specific table?

Tags: mysqldump

This question is related to [a question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/350679/27498) I posted on another StackExchange site.

Question: How to apply the `--where` argument only to a specific table when `mysqldump`-ing a whole database?

---

So I have a database with the DB contents of a WordPress blog. The table names look like this:

```
MariaDB [blog]> show tables;
+-------------------------+
| Tables_in_blog          |
+-------------------------+
| wp_commentmeta          |
| wp_comments             |
| wp_links                |
| wp_options              |
| wp_postmeta             |
| wp_posts                |
| wp_term_relationships   |
| wp_term_taxonomy        |
| wp_termmeta             |
| wp_terms                |
| wp_usermeta             |
| wp_users                |
+-------------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

There is one table here (`wp_comments`) whose contents I'd like to filter during backups (without dropping said records from the *actual* table; i.e. dropping them, then taking a backup isn't an option!).

```
MariaDB [blog]> describe wp_comments;
+----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field                | Type                | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| comment_ID           | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| comment_post_ID      | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
| comment_author       | tinytext            | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| comment_author_email | varchar(100)        | NO   | MUL |                     |                |
| comment_author_url   | varchar(200)        | NO   |     |                     |                |
| comment_author_IP    | varchar(100)        | NO   |     |                     |                |
| comment_date         | datetime            | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| comment_date_gmt     | datetime            | NO   | MUL | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| comment_content      | text                | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| comment_karma        | int(11)             | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| comment_approved     | varchar(20)         | NO   | MUL | 1                   |                |
| comment_agent        | varchar(255)        | NO   |     |                     |                |
| comment_type         | varchar(20)         | NO   |     |                     |                |
| comment_parent       | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
| user_id              | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
+----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The filtering condition should be `where comment_approved not in ('spam', 'trash')`. For comparison of the number of comments:

```
MariaDB [blog]> select count(*) from wp_comments where comment_approved not in ('spam', 'trash');
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     1392 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [blog]> select count(*) from wp_comments;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    12477 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Almost a 1:10 ratio of ham:spam for the number of comments. Anyway, the gist is that I'd like to thin out my backups a bit and considering that - at this moment - the SQL dump gets blown up by (`wp_comments` table alone) roughly 42 MiB by the spam/trash comments, I'd like to exclude them from the hourly backups altogether:

```
42.957 MiB      ./spam.sql
928.000 KiB     ./nospam.sql
```

Now I understand that I could write myself some ugly shell script in order to achieve what I want by basically:

1. enumerating the tables of the DB to be dumped
2. dump the tables one by one, all the while

   - applying `where` clauses specific to respective tables

However, if I am not careful (e.g. if I'd hardcode the list of tables) this could turn out to be a rather brittle (and lossy) backup solution down the road. For example when WordPress introduces a new table and I only find out months later ...

I guess what I'd need would be something along the lines of a command line option that allows to give the predicate of a `WHERE` clause in a table-specific fashion, e.g. in a text file with `tablename: predicate` (instead of globally `--where=predicate`) ... or a more forgiving `--where` command line option which allows me to say `comment_approved not in ('spam', 'trash')` and does not barf if the columns in the predicate don't exist. However, I can see how this would be impossible for more complex `WHERE` clauses (`where t1.colx = t2.colz`). The last option that comes to mind would be something like `--where:tablename=predicate` which would complicate command line parsing and possibly introduce ambiguity as well.

Does anyone have a concise (i.e. not involving too much scripting on my part) solution for the problem of backing up one whole database while filtering out rows for a specific table based on a `WHERE` clause?

NB: I am using (on a Ubuntu 16.04 machine):

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.38-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

Comment: I think you know the answer to this already. Script time :)

Comment: If you don't back up those rows, that means you don't really care about them. If you have to restore a backup, those rows will be lost. So if you don't need the rows, why not just delete them? In WordPress, you can go to the spam folder and permanently delete them.

Comment: @AMtwo easy, because on occasion there are false positives. Backups are taken for disaster recovery, so in case of a disaster having lost a handful of wrongly flagged comments isn't too big a deal. But during normal operation you don't want an hourly backup job to clean out your (automatically) flagged comments, because it means you never get a chance to review _any_ of them.

Comment: My point is actually not that you should be automatically deleting the spam comments-- but that you should be backing them all up. And if the backup size is a concern, someone should go into Spam folder in WordPress, review them, and permanently delete all the spam.

Comment: @AMtwo well, another comment on the related question already pushed me into the direction of backing up junk comments for another reason. The claim being that some plugins retain junk comments to classify newly created comments. And I'm sorry, but your initial comment didn't really get that point across (to me)! Now there are still ways to tweak this. For example I could only ever keep the very latest junk comments (e.g. prune backups of them more aggressively) and so on. But cleaning out junk comments at the frequency you propose won't work (for me). Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Tablenames that are added in (future) version of WordPress should not be a problem when you are scripting this solution

If a take a look at my 'test' database:

```
SELECT 
  TABLE_NAME, 
  CASE TABLE_NAME WHEN 'big' THEN "i<10" ELSE "1" END AS filter 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='test';
```

I do see something like this:

```
+---------------------------+--------+
| TABLE_NAME                | filter |
+---------------------------+--------+
| a                         | 1      |
| abd                       | 1      |
| below                     | 1      |
| big                       | i<10   |
| categories                | 1      |
```

These results could also be stored in a table (i.e. MY_BACKUP_FILTERS), and a real script-guru could easily create a script around this output.

something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

DATABASE=test
HOST=******
USERNAME=luuk
PASSWORD=*******
FILTERSQL='SELECT
  TABLE_NAME,
  CASE TABLE_NAME
  WHEN "big" THEN "i<10"
  ELSE "1" END AS filter
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="test";'
TMP=/tmp/tmp.$$

mysql -h $HOST -u $USERNAME -p$PASSWORD -B -N -e "$FILTERSQL" >$TMP

cat $TMP | while read line
do
        table=`echo -e "$line" | cut -f 1`
        filter=`echo -e "$line" | cut -f 2`
        #echo TABLE:$table, FILTER:$filter
        mysqldump -h $HOST $DATABASE $table -u $USERNAME -p$PASSWORD -w "$filter"
done
```

This script will dump all tables except the table 'big', for which only the records are dump `WHERE i<10`

Adding/changing 'WHEN ...' to the statement a line #12 in the script will add more filters for other tables.